# Procedure is not getting called in entity framework using DbRawSqlQry

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am calling stored procedure in following way. But when I am watching it in sqlProfiler the no call has been made by entity framework to execute stored procedure.

```
 objUnit.dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResellerCustomerFile>("USP_ResellerCustomerFile_DeleteFiles @CustomerId, @FileId, @IsFile",
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", customerId),
                new SqlParameter("@FileId", fileId),
                new SqlParameter("@IsFile", 1));
```

If I change my code by adding **.Tolist(), .FirstOrDefault() etc.** at end of the above statement then call is recorded in SqlProfiler but it fills datareader and starts mapping the records from data reader as I have passed **TEntity**.

But my stored procedure only updates records and don't return any thing. Now how can I call my stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `objUnit.dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of `objUnit.dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResellerCustomerFile>`.

`SqlQuery` expects a return value, that is why you had to declare `ResellerCustomerFile` as the generic return type.

`ExecuteSqlCommand` is a command without return value, use this method to execute your command directly.

```
objUnit.dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("USP_ResellerCustomerFile_DeleteFiles @CustomerId, @FileId, @IsFile",
    new SqlParameter("@CustomerId", customerId),
    new SqlParameter("@FileId", fileId),
    new SqlParameter("@IsFile", 1));
```